# Обработка списка

Tags: python

Есть реальный список  row:

```
row=['1101516021', '0', '1', '', 'TTT', 'ppp', '997476042736', '', '20150320092249', '20150320092249', '1', '1', '110', '', '', '00', '22', '', '999470000032', '40711569', '', '1', '0']
```

Его необходимо инсертить в БД. Но перед инсертом обработать так:

```
row[8]="to_date('"+row[8]+"','yyyymmddhh24miss')"
row[9]="to_date('"+row[9]+"','yyyymmddhh24miss')"
row[3]="'"+row[3]+"'" 
row[4]="'"+row[4]+"'" 
row[5]="'"+row[5]+"'" 
row[6]="'"+row[6]+"'" 
row[7]="'"+row[7]+"'" 
row[11]="'"+row[11]+"'"
row[12]="'"+row[12]+"'"
row[13]="'"+row[13]+"'"
row[14]="'"+row[14]+"'"
row[15]="'"+row[15]+"'"
row[16]="'"+row[16]+"'"
row[17]="'"+row[17]+"'"
row[18]="'"+row[18]+"'"
row[19]="'"+row[19]+"'"
row[0]="0"+row[0]
row[1]="0"+row[1]
row[2]="0"+row[2]
row[10]="0"+row[10]
row[20]="0"+row[20]
row[21]="0"+row[21]
row[22]="0"+row[22]
```

Получилось очень громоздко и некрасиво.
А хотелось что-то типа

```
row[3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]= ["'"+x+"'" for x in row[3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19]]
```

Но, к сожалению, в питоне так писать нельзя.

Comment: Ответ в вопросе?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял, вам нужно, в частности, заключать в кавычки те записи, которые не состоят полностью из цифр, в том числе и пустые строки. По этому условию можно все и обработать:

```
row=['1101516021', '0', '1', '', 'TTT', 'ppp', '997476042736', '', '20150320092249', '20150320092249', '1', '1', '110', '', '', '00', '22', '', '999470000032', '40711569', '', '1', '0']
for i, item in enumerate(row):
    if not item or not all(x.isnumeric() for x in item):
        row[i] = "'" + row[i] + "'"
print(row)
```

Результат:

```
['1101516021', '0', '1', "''", "'TTT'", "'ppp'", '997476042736', "''", '20150320092249', '20150320092249', '1', '1', '110', "''", "''", '00', '22', "''", '999470000032', '40711569', "''", '1', '0']
```

Answer (score 1):

В питоне можно писать проще и красивее. Ваш код будет выглядеть где-то так (две строки, потому что есть разрыв):

```
row[3:7] = ["'"+x+"'" for x in row[3:7]]
row[11:19] = ["'"+x+"'" for x in row[11:19]]
```

Comment: Вы используете срез row[3,7]
А мне надо перечислить конкретные позиции 
row[3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19] тут два среза 3:7 и 11:19
А если мне надо в списке из 100 элементов обработать 20 не подряд идущих и между порядками которых нет никакой взаимосвязи?

Comment: А почему тогда не написать банальный for?

   ind = (1,4,23,100)
   for i in ind:
      row[i] = '"'+row[i]+'"'

Ваш способ с перечислением плох, так как приходиться дублировать список, а на больших списках чревато ошибками.

Но можно и так написать, если хочется через генератор

    row=['1101516021', '0', '1', '', 'TTT', 'ppp', '997476042736', '', '20150320092249', '20150320092249', '1', '1', '110', '', '', '00', '22', '', '999470000032', '40711569', '', '1', '0']
    ind = (3,4,5,6,7,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19)

    row = [ "'"+row[i]+"'" if i in ind else row[i] for i in xrange(0,len(row))